# Rotate image when hover on other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I'm trying to create something real simple. But I don't know why it isn't working?
This is what I'm trying: http://www.yannickluijten.be/test
when I hover the green, blue, gray or yellow div the image in the middle has to rotate.
Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('#green').hover(function(){     
    $('#rotator').addClass('rotate_green');    
},     
function(){    
    $('#rotator').removeClass('rotate_green');     
});

$('#blue').hover(function(){     
    $('#rotator').addClass('rotate_blue');    
},     
function(){    
    $('#rotator').removeClass('rotate_blue');     
});

$('#gray').hover(function(){     
    $('#rotator').addClass('rotate_gray');    
},     
function(){    
    $('#rotator').removeClass('rotate_gray');     
});

$('#yellow').hover(function(){     
    $('#rotator').addClass('rotate_yellow');    
},     
function(){    
    $('#rotator').removeClass('rotate_yellow');     
});
});
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to include jQuery API file. Please include it in your code. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: Yes offcourse, that's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include jQuery.js on your code.
Add this line in HEAD section
`http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js`

Comment: What image, central one? You can remove class resonance on mouse out even and it will stay "rotated". BUT, if you need true rotation than you have to write more flexible code.